# Adapt to iPhone's in-call status bar with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mobile, jqtouch

When my web app is used while the user is in a call, or using personal hotspot, everything is pushed down by the green or blue bar that comes up on the phone.

Is there a way to make the app adapt with Javascript or any way that might work for jQtouch or jQuery mobile based apps & pages?